# Mapped network drives from bash on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bash, cygwin

How can I access mapped network drives while using bash on Windows 10. I can access the local drives via /mnt but not the network mapped drives.

Most of the available solutions suggest cygwin which i have been using on Windows 8 - was wondering if there is anyway bash shell on win 10 could do it as well. I already have the drives mapped and can access via explorer.

Comment: what is the output of `ls /cygdrive` ?

Comment: cygwin shows everything including the mapped network drives under /cygdrive

Comment: so why you don't access though `/cygdrive/<you drive letter> ` that is the canonical way ?

Comment: Once you are inside bash in command prompt, the /cygdrive is not available for access. cygdrive is available only inside the Cygwin terminal.

Comment: not true. Bash environment does not depend from which terminal is run. Or you are running a different user or something else is different